# Can I search a file according to specific character types?

Tags: grep, ls, search

Im looking to search through a file containing a list of license plates.

If the license plates are formatted as  ABAA BAB, where A is a number and B is the letter of an alphabet, is it possible to search and get a list of all plates similar in formatting?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some more specific examples?

Comment: Also, for your example you could simply do `grep '^[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9] [A-Z][0-9][0-9]$' /path/to/file` but I guess that's not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just extract all the license plates that match that pattern from a file:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9][A-Z][0-9]{2} [A-Z][0-9]{2}' /path/to/file
```